# Translating method signatures from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, methods, signature

Currently I'm translating a class from Objective-C to apple Swift, but unfortunately I've no idea about Objective-C so any help in translating the signature of the following function from Objective-C to Swift?

```
- (void)playbackSession:(id<BCOVPlaybackSession>)session didReceiveLifecycleEvent:(BCOVPlaybackSessionLifecycleEvent *)lifecycleEvent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature in Swift would look like:

```
func playbackSession(session: AnyObject<BCOVPlayBackSession>!, didReceiveLifecycleEvent event:BCOVPlaybackSessionLifecycleEvent!)
```

Answer (score 8):

Upping this question to provide a more generic answer:

- Use the "Related Items" button on the top left of your code window in XCode (right next to the "<" and ">" navigation arrows)
- From the menu it opens, select "Generated interface" and choose your Swift version of choice. Voilà!

See capture of the "Related items" menu:

[image: Related Items menu in XCode]

Comment: THIS is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!